# Autosave using javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following piece of code autosaves a page but it also times it out by loging out and taking the user to a time out page.  How can i chnage it so that it only does the auto save part but not the time out?

```
<script language='javascript'>
    function Save() {
        var hdnSessionTimeOut = document.getElementById('fast22_MainCtn_fast44');
        hdnSessionTimeOut.value = 'SessionTimeOut';
        __doPostBack('Fast22$MainCtn$btnSave', '');
    }

    function Redirect() {
        window.location = "SessionTimeout.aspx"
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        if ('True' == 'True') setTimeout(Save, 30000);
        else setTimeout(Redirect, 30000);
    }
</script>
```

I tried reducing it to the following but and I think it worked but it changed the doc to view mode instead of edit mode. and you have to click edit again. Also when it in edit mode, the counter still works and it gives and error.  Is there a way to have it auto save and then go back again to edit mode?

```
<script language='javascript'> 
function Save() { 
__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$btnSave', ''); 
} 

window.onload = function () { 
if ('True' == 'True') setTimeout(Save, 10000); 
else setTimeout(Save, 25000); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Are you aware what `if ('True' == 'True')` means/does?

Comment: Yes, it mean it will always be true. Not sure what the original coder was trying to accomplish from that..

Comment: Regardless, you don't need it that way for sure. Plus you probably have a confusion about redirect and session timeout. The two are independent, but that's for another time. The question is, if you don't want neither redirect nor save, why call those functions at all?

Comment: They are already called in the head tags. Since I don't have access to the html, I want to add something to body that will overwrite it and just save without redirecting the page.